# VB.NET - Convert String Representation of a Byte Array back into a Byte Array

Tags: vb.net, string, pdf-generation, arrays

I have an application that makes a call to a third party web API that returns a `String` that looks something like this:

```
"JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48/TDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL1R5cGUgL091dGxpbmVzDQovQ291bnQgMA0KPj4NCmVuZG9iag0KMiAwIG9iag0KDQpbL1BERiAvVGV4dCAvSW1hZ2VDXQ0KZW"
```

(It's actually much longer than that but I'm hoping just the small snippet is enough to recognize it without me pasting a string a mile long)

The documentation says it returns a `Byte` array but when I try to accept it as a `Byte` array directly, I get errors. Part of my problem here is that the documentation isn't completely clear what the `Byte` array represents. Since it's a GetReport function I'm calling, I'm guessing it's a PDF but I'm not 100% sure as the documentation doesn't say at all.

So, anyway, I'm getting this `String` and I'm trying to convert it to a PDF. Here's what that looks like:

```
Dim reportString As String = GetValuationReport(12345, token.SecurityToken)

Dim report As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(reportString)
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\filepath\myreport.pdf", report)
```

I'm pretty sure that the middle line converts the `String` into a new `Byte` array rather than simply converting it into its `Byte` array equivalent but I don't know how to do that.

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your string may be [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded, in which case you would use this to convert it to bytes:

```
Dim report As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(reportString)
```

Comment: Ha! You're a genius. That's exactly what my problem was.